# Approximation of the discrete random variable resulting from many convolutions of the same random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Following the linearity of expectation, for some discrete random variable $X$, and its expectation $E[X]$, expectation of $n$ occurrences of $X$ would be computed simply as $E[X] \times n$, rather than computing $n$ convolutions of $X$ and then computing the expectancy of the final random variable resulting from those convolutions.

Is there any similar computation or at least approximation that might derive the final random variable resulting from those $n$ convolutions, instead of actually computing all $n$ convolutions? This is important since convolutions exhibit exponential time complexity.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is using the central limit theorem to approximate it as a certain normal distribution. Rather, since $X_1+\dots+X_n$ is discrete, you find the approximating continuous normal variable $Z$, then $P(X_1+\dots+X_n=k)\approx P(k-\frac12<Z<k+\frac12)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you Mike. I was thinking about using central limit theorem, especially because as $n$ grows, the distribution tends towards a nicely shaped continuous normal distribution. What is the best method to approximate $Z$? And is there any way to over-approximate it, such that $P(X_1 + ... + X_n = k)$ is slightly less than $P(k-1/2 < Z<k+1/2)$ or some other similar approximation? What is important is that the CDF of the approximation is bellow the CDF of the exact convolution result, for any k. Thank you once more!